# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'toSource'

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I've download a PDF file on my local disk ('Downloads' folder). When I double click on it PDF 'Reader' from my windows 8.1 system try to load it.

All I can see on all pages is:

> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'toSource'

[image: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'toSource']

For some reason quickly moving from page to page allow me to glance the real page. As a side note, I also cannot open this file from Chrome:

[image: Open PDF in chrome (open with)]

Is there a way for me to display this PDF in Reader ?

Comment: As the issue appears to be related to the specific PDF, please share it for analysis.

Comment: I can't. Internal document

Comment: Then you most likely have to ask internal experts.